# Firebase rules, limiting access to only participating users

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Trying to implement so that the user only can access game data for games that user is playing.
Basically, if the user is part of the list of players, user shall be able to read. I have a list of participating players in all $GameID.
All users have their own unique username stored under Users -> FirebaseID -> Username value.

I can get the following to work when simulating reading a child in a $GameID where the user is part of but it does not give the user access when I try lite in my app.

Call in app:

```
GamesDataDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Games");
GamesDataDatabase.limitToFirst(50).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ......
```

Rules:

```
"Games": {
      "$GameID": {
                ".read": "root.child('Games').child($GameID).child('metaData').child('players').child(root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('username').val()).exists()",
```

Does not seem to be any difference if I replace "data" with root.child('Games').child($GameID)

Data structure:
[image: Data tree]

Tried things back and forth but does not seem to be able to get this rule working... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem starts here code:

```
GamesDataDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Games");
GamesDataDatabase.limitToFirst(50).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...
```

This code will only work if the user has read permission to `/Games`. If they don't have read permission to `/Games` it will fail with a "permission denied".

Combining this with the fact that you cannot take permissions away on a lower level, this means that you cannot use Firebase security rules to filter data.

This is known as ["rules are not filters" in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters), and is a common source of confusion for developers who are new to Firebase's security model. I recommend that you study some of the [previous questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase%5d%20rules%20are%20not%20filters) to learn more.

Comment: Would this work if I were to move over to Cloud Firsestore (the new beta program)?

Comment: I think that may be indeed be possible with the rules described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/secure-data#shallow_queries But I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to add read: false to Games and due to the build up of Firebase Realtime Database, it shall check the next level (child) for access?
I tried this but got the same result, my user in the app did not get access... (Even if the simulation gives access....)

Comment: A listener attached to `/Games` will only work if the user has read permission to `/Games`. If they don't have read permission to `/Games` it will fail with a "permission denied".